# How can we adjust the height of row in sap.m.table?

Tags: javascript, sapui5

I am creating a table using `sap.m.Table` in controller. How can I adjust my row size of the table?

I am using `sap.m.ColumnListItem` to add each row, but there is no option provided by table or `ColumnListItem` to adjust the height of the row

```
onDataGotFromServer : function(data){
    var table = new sap.m.Table({
        showSeparators: "None"
    });
    var column1 = new sap.m.Column();
    var column2 = new sap.m.Column();
    table.addColumn(column1);
    table.addColumn(column2);
    for( var i=0; i < data.length; i++ ) {
        var eachData = data[i];
        var columnListItem = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
            cells:[
                new sap.m.Text({
                    text: eachData.key
                }),
                new sap.m.Text({
                    text: eachData.value
                })
            ]
        });
        table.addItem(columnListItem);
    }
    this._layout.addContent(table);         
}
```

Here is the code for demo : https://plnkr.co/edit/sKYK9R5a5fFJdJ8D68GF?p=preview

Comment: Kindly share more information for better understanding, like screenshots would be helpful.

Comment: Row size means row height?

Comment: try adding this `table.addStyleClass("sapUiSizeCompact");`

Comment: Yes I mean Row Height only

Comment: You could add a margin to the inner cells of the row. This should lead to a higher row. I wouldn add the Style class compact mode, because it scales the height just down.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another quick way to work this out:

You can use HBox or VBox to put your Texts and then apply height on the HBox. Following is an example as per your plunker.

```js
var columnListItem = new sap.m.ColumnListItem({
  cells: [

    new sap.m.HBox({
      height: "60px",
      items: [
        new sap.m.Text({
          text: "Test1"
        })
      ]
    }),
    new sap.m.HBox({
      items: [
        new sap.m.Text({
          text: "Test2"
        })
      ]
    })
  ]
});
```

Let me know if this helps!

Answer (score 0):

There is no property provided for width setting according to the API Reference for [sap.m.ColumnListItem](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.ColumnListItem/constructor).

But you can use `css` with unique `IDs` for the columnListItems to control individual cells.

```js
sap.ui.define([
  "sap/m/Text", "sap/m/Column", "sap/m/ColumnListItem", "sap/m/Table"

], function(Text, Column, ColumnListItem, Table) {
  "use strict";

  var table = new Table({
    width: "50%",
    showSeparators: "None"
  }).placeAt("content");

  var column1 = new Column();
  var column2 = new Column();
  table.addColumn(column1);
  table.addColumn(column2);

  for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {

    var columnListItem = new ColumnListItem("cols" + i, {
      vAlign: "Middle",
      cells: [
        new Text({
          text: "Test1",
          width: "3rem"

        }),
        new Text({
          text: "Test2",
          width: "3rem"
        })
      ]
    });
    table.addItem(columnListItem);
  }
});
```

```css
/* Styles go here */

.sapMListTbl {
  width: 70% !important
}

.sapMListTblRow {
  height: 2rem !important;
}

.sapMListTblCell {
  text-align: center !important;
}

#cols0 { /* Row 1 */
  text-align: left !important;
  background: aqua;
  height: 5rem !important;
}

#cols1_cell1 { /* Row 2, cell2 */
   background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<title>SAPUI5 Walkthrough</title>
<script id="sap-ui-bootstrap" src="https://openui5.hana.ondemand.com/resources/sap-ui-core.js" data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize" data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m" data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge" data-sap-ui-async="true" data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{
   "sap.ui.demo.walkthrough": "./"
  }'>
</script>

<body class="sapUiBody" id="content">
</body>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: she's asking about height, not width